# Bind9 configure part of public TLD for private network devices

Tags: configuration, dns, bind, domain, private-network

Our company controls a domain called `foobar.com`, which is used for various public services (w.g. `www.foobar.com` directs to our website). The domain has public DNS records in a DNS service.

We have some internal network devices which we were hoping to assign names for using subdomains of the `foobar.com` TLD.

How can Bind9 be configured as such:

1. First check if a public DNS server has defined a domain for some IP address
2. If not, then check an internal DNS server whether it has defined the domain for some internal IP address
3. If that fails, fail the lookup "normally".

Currently, our config incorrectly operates on an "on/off" basis, e.g. it either reads the public DNS or the private DNS, not both. This makes it unusable as we want to access both public and private DNS records at the same time.

The DNS servers are managed separately, and the private DNS is on a local device with Bind9 installed.

I've tried the following:

1. Have something like this in the private DNS records

   ```
   IN NS privatens.foobar.com ; the private (local) DNS
   IN NS publicns.foobar.com ; the public DNS
   ```
2. Set forwarding in `named.conf.options` to public DNS servers

   ```
   options {
       forwarders { ... };
       forward first;
   };
   ```
3. Juggle with priority inside `resolv.conf`

None of these seem to work. Examples:

`www.foobar.com` points to a web server using public DNS. `printer.office.foobar.com` is a CNAME to `unique1.foobar.com` which is an A record to `192.168.5.10`. I want queries to `www.foobar.com` to work with public DNS and queries `printer.office.foobar.com` to work with private DNS.

Now all queries to `printer.office.foobar.com` work, but all queries to `www.foobar.com` result in an NXDOMAIN response and halt there.

Is it even possible to read two different zones for a single domain (e.g. `foobar.com`) or will it just ignore the other?

EDIT:

To make the issue more clear, I've made this super nifty diagram of our network and the external thingies:

[image]

Anything inside the orange is our private network, with no access from outside. The things inside green are public servers with domain names set to them. `192.168.5.1` is our router, `192.168.5.5` is our private DNS server, and `ns1.dnsprovider.com` is some DNS server provided by a 3rd party.

Assuming I'm the user on `192.168.5.100` I want the following to happen:

1. When querying for `user1.foobar.com` I get the DNS results from `privns.foobar.com/192.168.5.5`.
2. When querying for `www.foobar.com` or `sub.foobar.com` I get the DNS results from `ns1.dnsprovider.com`

Comment: Ah thanks, I'll try searching with those terms!

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible configurations is to have different *internal* and *external* assignments to a domain is BIND views. Typically  this setup is done in a single server.

BIND views allow you to have different records in the same domain whether people are viewing it from the inside or the outside, or more interestingly, the same records with different IP addresses. (for instance addresses that map via NAT to different external addresses in others not to burden your border firewall with internal traffic).

The advantage of such setup is having to maintain two (or more) separate zones for the same domain.

To define the view you simply define in the 1st view to which networks it answers, and the rest will be shown the second view.

As in, in `named.conf`:

```
acl networks1 { 192.168.1.0/24; 192.168.3.0/24; };
acl networks2 { 192.168.2.0/24; };

view "nets1" {
    match-clients { networks1; };
    recursion yes;

    include "mydomain.view1";
}

view "nets2" {
    match-clients { networks2; };
    recursion yes;

    include "mydomain.view2"; 
}
```

See:[Understanding views in BIND 9, by example](https://kb.isc.org/article/AA-00851/0/Understanding-views-in-BIND-9-by-example.html)

Comment: I'm looking for adjusting the DNS request by _destination_, not _source_. We're not allowing external access to the DNS server. Users need to be able to query both DNS servers from a single source IP in the private network.

Comment: changed it accordingly, I hope. What do you understand by destination? The views defined are the networks of the clients.

Comment: Destination is a server either inside a local network or an external network. Sources (clients) are solely inside a single private network (e.g. 192.168.1.0/24).